# How to Translate things in Liferay 7

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I've read the Article about [how to modify language keys](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/modifying-liferays-language-keys) inLiferay 7, but there are no hints how to translate more than one language. I want to Translate things in my Theme and that was very easy in liferay 6.x, but I don't know how to do this in in liferay 7.

Edit: What I have done before:

1. create a [resourcebundle project with blade](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/maven/blade.resourcebundle)
2. edit the Language.properties file and deploy it to my liferay 7 server to test the function
3. create a Language_de.properties file, build and deploy it to liferay

You have to set the `property = {"language.id=xx_XX"}` in your Class to define **one** language. If you just add another Language_xx_XX.properties file, it just won't work.

My question here is: How can I add more Languages to my resourcebundle?

Comment: I'd guess you can still use Language_fr.properties, Language_es.properties, Language_de.properties for translating more than one language? Can you add some more details to your post and define a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a resource bundle that modifies Liferay's core language keys, I think you can only modify one locale's translations per bundle.

If you're overriding keys from a module deployed to the OSGi runtime (that's where most keys are going to be), you'd follow [this tutorial](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/overriding-a-modules-language-keys). I believe you simply add any language files whose keys you want to override in this case.

> Create properly named language properties files for each locale whose
>   keys you want to override. These should go in src/content, and are the
>   resource bundles that are loaded by the resource bundle loader you are
>   implementing.

Answer (score 0):

"If you just add another Language_xx_XX.properties file, it just won't work."

Why? If it doesn't work, make sure that you've mentioned this file in portlet.xml file:

```
<resource-bundle>content/Language</resource-bundle>
```

After that, you can use a language key in your JSP via a `<liferay-ui:message />` tag.